# Hiding list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries

I am using this trick to display the list of figures only if there is at least one figure in my document:

```
\ifnum\value{figure}>0
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
\fi
```

Is there a way to do this with the `glossaries`-package?

```
\usepackage[
    acronym=true,
    toc
]{glossaries}
\makeglossary

[...]

\glsaddall
\printglossary[
    type=\acronymtype,
    title=Foo,
    numberedsection,
    nonumberlist
]

[...]

\glsaddall
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\printglossary[
    title=Glossary,
    numberedsection,
    nonumberlist
]
```

I thought about defining wrapper commands for the `\newacronym` and `\newglossaryentry` commands and setting a boolean variable to true.

Comment: Do you print your LoF and/or Glossaries at the end of the document?

Comment: Yes, at the end of the document.

Comment: Could you provide the community with a [minimal example](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) (not just the code snippets you've provided) that shows the use of both acronyms and glossaries in the document?

Comment: The default behaviour is that `\printglossary` does absolutely nothing if you don't use any entries, but you appear to  overriding that with `\glsaddall` which says to include all defined entries regardless of use.  Could you give a full example showing when you want the glossary to be suppressed?